# VB.NET/ASP.NET 4.0 custom configuration section: "An error occurred creating the configuration section handler"

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, web-config, app-config, asp.net-4.0

I am creating a custom config section that will allow me to manage what ELMAH exceptions I want to ignore from my VB.NET/ASP.NET app.  Here's my code.  I made it easy to paste in a blank code file if anyone's up to the challenge of diagnosing the problem.

```
Imports System.Configuration
Namespace ElmahExceptionHandling
    Public Class IgnoredExceptionSection : Inherits ConfigurationSection
        <ConfigurationProperty("IgnoredExceptions")>
        ReadOnly Property IgnoredExceptions As IgnoredExceptions
            Get
                Return TryCast(Me("IgnoredExceptions"), IgnoredExceptions)
            End Get
        End Property
        Shared Function GetConfig() As IgnoredExceptionSection

            Return TryCast(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("IgnoredExceptionSection"), IgnoredExceptionSection)

        End Function
    End Class

    <ConfigurationCollection(GetType(IgnoredException))>
    Public Class IgnoredExceptions : Inherits ConfigurationElementCollection
        Protected Overloads Overrides Function CreateNewElement() As System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement

            Return New IgnoredException

        End Function
        Protected Overrides Function GetElementKey(element As System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement) As Object

            Return TryCast(element, IgnoredException).Message

        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class IgnoredException : Inherits ConfigurationElement
        <ConfigurationProperty("Message")>
        ReadOnly Property Message As String
            Get
                Return Me("Message")
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And here's the config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="IgnoredExceptionSection" type="ElmahExceptionHandling.IgnoredExceptionSection, WEB" />
</configSections>
<IgnoredExceptionSection>
    <IgnoredExceptions>
        <add Message="test exception" />
    </IgnoredExceptions>
</IgnoredExceptionSection>
```

When I execute this code:

```
Dim section As ElmahExceptionHandling.IgnoredExceptionSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("IgnoredExceptionSection")
```

I get the error `An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for IgnoredExceptionSection: Could not load file or assembly 'WEB' or one of its dependencies.`.

What boggles my mind is that this all works fine in my C# console test app after I convert the code from VB.NET using a web utility.  However, when I paste the VB code from my web app into my VB.NET console test app, it doesn't work there, either, so it appears to be a C#/VB issue.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Comment: I suppose this question is downvoted because folks don't like the idea of doing away with an exception in this fashion.  The downvoters have not given any reason for thier downvotes (quite an unproductive approach to Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration file, there is an unneeded entry at the end of your type declaration.  Try changing this line:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="IgnoredExceptionSection"  type="ElmahExceptionHandling.IgnoredExceptionSection, WEB" />
</configSections>
```

To this

```
<configSections>
    <section name="IgnoredExceptionSection" type="ElmahExceptionHandling.IgnoredExceptionSection" />
</configSections>
```

Comment: I've tried that before and I still get the error message.  My config line looks just like this:
`<section name="IgnoredExceptionSection" type="ElmahExceptionHandling.IgnoredExceptionSection" />`

Comment: Did you try your solution in a test app or something?  I set up the code so that it's easy to paste into a simple console app.  It works in my C# app, but not my VB.NET app.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: I have tried c# and vb websites with your code both failed. Then I followed Mike comment, now both works perfect. Don't know what is your issue. Doesn't matter whether you have tried that solution earlier or not. Your question section still hold that information which is incorrect. Try this solution and post your error message. That will help us analyse and see what else is going wrong.

Comment: By the way if you wish to you this custom config in your console app then you have to add your application name in the config (<yourapplicationname>.exe ) <configSections>
    <section name="IgnoredExceptionSection" type="ElmahExceptionHandling.IgnoredExceptionSection, yourapplicationname" />
</configSections>